Using age as 'timescale' for Cox Model in lifelines [Python]?
I came across several methods of defining the timescale when performing a cox regression.
The two main ones are:

time in study
age of participant

Example of time-on-study as the time-scale:
o=censored X=event
------------------------------o 36 months
--------------------------o 34
------------o 18
-------X 12
------------------X 24
------------------------------o 36
0        12         24          36
Months since baseline 

Example of age as the time-scale:
o=censored X=event
50-----o 53
     52----------o 55
                  54----------X 57
                          55------------o 58
                                  56--------------o 59
                                            58---------o 60
Age in years 

In R the way to incorporate age as time-scale is to use the code:
Surv(age, age + time, status)
Is there a way to do the same for lifelines package in Python? From the docs the current CoxPHFitter only takes in a duration_col. How do I incorporate the age in this column?
from lifelines import CoxPHFitter
cph = CoxPHFitter()

# example lifelines fit but
# how to fit age in function?
cph.fit(inputDf, 
    duration_col='timeToDiagnosis',
    event_col='caseCancer', 
    formula="age + sex")

The duration_col only takes in one column in a dataframe, hence setting the "time difference" in years is essentially similar to 1). Also, I could just incorporate age within the model covariates - though I think this is fundamentally different to allowing the model to evaluate age in the person-years / hazard estimation.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I have added code where the duration_col is used within the function.

David, if you don't get a response here, you could try stats.stackexchange.com instead.

Thanks Robert, I have cross posted there.

stats.stackexchange.com does not accept the question and it is closed. So this one remains open, I will post on the github of lifelines as well

Posting what I have found here, as a documentation since I could not find it clearly explained from Google searches or elsewhere on stackoverflow, or the github page. This should help in case someone else has the same query in the future.
To clarify some terminology: For the second scenario, incorporating age as the timescale can also be termed as left truncation and right censoring. This is standard description on the type of survival analysis, and is commonly used in biological and medical fields. Left truncation by age here means that the individual is not enrolled since birth but enters the study at a particular age. Right censoring here occurs when an event happens, ie. death, outcome, or lost to followup. I won't go into details on the types of censoring which is out of scope for the question but covered extensively here.
To answer the above question: to incorporate the left-truncation in Python there is a parameter entry to specify the age of entry. This API is similar in both lifelines and statsmodels. For an illustrative example and to demonstrate equivalence to R (I'm using KM plots here just for a visual example):
from lifelines import datasets
from lifelines import KaplanMeierFitter
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
df = datasets.load_psychiatric_patients()

fig, ax =  plt.subplots()

for i, sex in enumerate(df['sex'].unique()):
    mask = f'sex == {sex}'
    kmf = KaplanMeierFitter()
    # specify entry column here as a pandas series of ages
    kmf.fit(
        durations=df.query(mask)["Age"] + df.query(mask)['T'],
        event_observed=df.query(mask)['C'],
        entry=df.query(mask)["Age"]
    )
    kmf.plot_survival_function(
        color=f'C{i + 1}',
        label=sex,
        ax=ax
    )

ax.set(
    title='Kaplan-Meier survival [Python]',
    xlabel='Years',
    ylabel='Estimated Probability of Survival'
)

library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(KMsurv)
data(psych); attach(psych)

my.surv.object <- Surv(age, age+time, death)

my.fit <- survfit(my.surv.object~sex)
ggsurvplot(my.fit, main="Kaplan-Meier estimate [R]",
     xlab="time", ylab="survival function")


Shows similar outputs in both lifelines in Python and survival in R.
Additional notes:
There is no need to add age in the model covariates for cox regression if the age timescale is used [3].
References:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/467186/understanding-left-truncated-data-in-survival-analysis
Age as a time scale in survival analysis
https://www.usu.edu/math/jrstevens/biostat/projects2013/pres_LeftTruncation.pdf

